# lost in the mist: actions in redux/reactjs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to wrap my head around both the theory and practice of implementing actions in reactjs...and I'm stuck!
ok - let's start with a thumbnail of my simple app test app:

1. I am creating a simple App that consists of a bunch of bootstrap buttons
2. I have a reducer that defines the properties of these buttons (snippet below):

   ```
   {id:                 1,
   name:               'Power',
   type:               'btn',
   activeStyle:        'btn-primary',
   defaultStyle:       'btn-primary',
   selectedStyle:      'btn-success',
   disabledStyle:      'btn-default',
   labelText:          'Power Status',
   labelTextSize:      '3',
   labelTextStyle:     'text-muted'},
   {id:                 '2'
   ......etc.....
   ```
3. I iterate through the store and create the buttons as components. It's working well.

   ```
   return this.props.deviceElements.map((deviceElement) => {
       return (<div>....{stuff}......</div>)
   ```
4. I have wired up a click event to the 'button'. It works.
5. What I want to do, for example, is:

   - click a button
   - if activeStyle = defaultStyle then make activeStyle = selectedStyle else make activeStyle = defaultStyle.
6. I have created a state in my component i.e. activeStyle and can happily switch the styles by changing that state in regular js code inside the onClick event using code like the below.

   ```
   if (activeStyle == this.props.element.defaultStyle)
   {activeStyle = this.props.element.selectedStyle} else 
   {activeStyle = this.props.element.defaultStyle}
   ```

Now onto my questions:

1. Should i be managing the app this way or should I be using actions...and why?
2. Regardless of the answer to #1, just how do I do that. I have tried every combination of defining actions, setting up action handlers in reducers and triggering them (dispatch) in my component....but I neither understand what is going on underneath the hood or how to get the code working. Would love a real life example (using this scenario) of how to do this.

Thanks.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
**After applying the code suggested below (I had to change a bit of it to get it working)....here's where I am.**

**UIComponent:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import {updateButtonStyle} from '../../actions/index';
```

---in my constructor:

```
this.state = {
    activeStyle: this.props.deviceElement.activeStyle};
```

later on....

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        deviceElements: state.deviceElements,
        activeStyle: state.deviceElements.activeStyle
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    updateButtonStyle,
  }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UIComponent);
```

to fire the action  (couldn't get it working at all without passing something!):

```
this.props.updateButtonStyle(this.activeStyle);
```

**Actions/index.js**

```
export const updateButtonStyle = (element) => {
  console.log("updateButtonStyle:")
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_BUTTON_STYLE',
    payload: element
  }
};
```

and finally, in my reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case "UPDATE_BUTTON_STYLE":
  return [
      ...state
    {style: 'btn-success'}
    ]
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

to get to this point, I have tried almost every combination I can think of. Finally, when I fire off the button press, it does indeed pass through the action and triggers the component to refresh itself...but I can't get anything to refresh and when I look in props, I see activeStyle as undefined...and when I look at state.activeStyle, it hasn't changed.

I'm missing something in this whole flow, I'm sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with Redux you should absolutely be using actions to change state, in this case `activeStyle`. The purpose of Redux is the maintain your application state in a single place, avoiding messy passing of props and state between components.

With Redux, you *connect* your actions and reducer state to your app, which allows a component to access actions and state with `this.props`. When you call `this.props.someaction` your action should return an action type, which is listened for in your reducer. Your reducer then updates the component state.

So in your case, you want to create an action and call it from your button's onPress event. All your action is doing is letting your reducer know what state change you want to make. It could be as simple as this:

```
function updateButtonStyle() {

  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_BUTTON_STYLE'
  }
}
```

And then in your reducer, you have the actual state change:

```
initialState = {};
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

      case UPDATE_BUTTON_STYLE:
        return {
          ...state,
          activeStyle: state.activeStyle == state.defaultStyle ? state.selectedStyle : state.defaultStyle
        }

      default:
        return state
      }
}
```

Now, assuming you have initialized your Redux store and connected it to your component, it's as simple as calling `this.props.updateButtonStyle()`. Redux will change the state for you. React/Redux takes some getting used to. At first it can seem really complicated and unclear how/where everything goes, but with a bit of practice it's an extremely clean way to keep track of/make changes to your app's state.

Comment: You should not set `this.state.activeStyle = this.props.deviceElement.activeStyle` . Use `this.props.deviceElement.activeStyle` directly. Also, you are not changing `activeStyle` in your reducer, but `style`, which I don't see defined or used anywhere else.

Comment: thanks. I deleted the state `activeStyle` and in my render area, I am using `this.props.deviceElement.activeStyle`. the `style` was a typo between various versions! Anyway - still doesn't seem to propogate back. When I look at the render function after the action, I see activeStyle as undefined. Getting closer I think. Perhaps it's what (or how) I'm returning out of the reducer?

Comment: by the way, in your code block, you set the state = initialState --- what is initialState? I'm guessing its pseudo-code for something....but can't figure out what.
also you suggest activeStyle: !state.activeStyle --- is that pseudoCode for 'set what you want it to be'? Thanks so much for prodding an dpoking me through this. Much appreciated.

Comment: can you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(state))` inside your "UPDATE_BUTTON_STYLE" reducer case?

Comment: returns:`[{"activeStyle":"btn-success","labelText":"try this"}]` 
(the labelText is just me dicking around to try and get something to work!)

Comment: sigh. alas I cannot use the props object in mapStateToProps context. Back to the drawing board. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change `mapStateToProps`. In your code try getting the state with `this.props.activeStyle` INSTEAD of `this.props.deviceElements.activeStyle`